# How to integrate incomplete gamma function?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, expected-value

This question is in light of the question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445330/probability-distribution-function-expressed-in-terms-of-a-divergent-series.

Let the pdf of $x$ be: 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{2\gamma(k+2/v, R^vx/\theta)(R^vx/\theta)^{-1-2/v}}{v\Gamma(k)}$$

where $R$, $k$ and $\theta$ are positive real, and $v$ is positive integer. I want to find $E[x]$ and $E[x^2]$ where, $E$ is the expected value. I know to find them we need: 
$$\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)dx, $$
$$\int_0^\infty x^2f_X(x)dx$$

How can I integrate a gamma function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of answers from a CAS (Mathematica 11.3): (The first two moments do not exist if $v$ is too small, as indicated.)  \begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \; x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{2 R^{-2v} \theta^2 \Gamma(k+1)}{(v-2)\Gamma(k)} &&, v>2  \\
\int_0^\infty \; x^2 f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{R^{-3v}\theta^3 \Gamma(k+2)}{(v-1)\Gamma(k)} &&, v>1  \text{.} 
\end{align*}
Given the fairly obvious pattern, does it extend?...
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \; x^3 f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{2 R^{-4v}\theta^4 \Gamma(k+3)}{(3v-2)\Gamma(k)}  \\
\int_0^\infty \; x^4 f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{-R^{-5v}\theta^5 \Gamma(k+4)}{(1-2v) \Gamma(k)}
\end{align*}
...  Not so much.

Comment: Thank you Eric, can you show me how you got to the result above?

Comment: @AymenKareem : As mentioned, I used a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).  Specifically, [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica) (version 11.3).